# Given a list of pair integer and another list of integers, group integers within range together

Tags: algorithm, search

Given a list of pair integer and another list of integers, group integers within range together.

For example, I have pair integers of list A

```
[[1,5], [13, 18] [6,9]]
```

And integers list of list B

```
[3, 15, 16, 7, 8, 9]
```

I would like the end results to be a map of

1,5 -> 3 
13,18 -> 15, 16 
6,9 -> 7,8,9

Currently, i can only think of loop through list B, and then loop through list A to check if the element is within the range (eg 3 >= 1 && 3 <= 5). O(N^2)

Is there a O(N) more efficient solution, thank you.

Comment: you can sort both array and then use a 2 pointer approach. That would be `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the input? I don't think it can be done faster than O(n log n) in general case, either with sorting, as @user1984 suggested, or using [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).